# Weird behavior in sh with `set -e` and a subshell

Tags: unix, posix, sh, dash-shell

The code below prints `Continuing` if I remove the subshell.
With the subshell, I need another succesful call after the test (using `:` as a succesful no-op command is most straightforward, IMO) if I want to get to the `Continuing` part.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e #Exit on untested error
( #Subshell
    #Some succesfful commands go here
    #And here comes a file test
    [ -f "doesntExist" ] && {
        : #Irrelevant
    }
    #: 
)
echo Continuing
```

Is this behavior correct? Why does introducing a subshell change the behavior of

```
[ -f "doesntExist" ] && {
      : 
}
```

I'm  using the `dash 0.5.7-2ubuntu2` to run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. `set -e` ignores a non-zero exit status from an AND-list, but not from a subshell. The difference between

```
set -e
[ -f "doesntExist" ] && {
    : #Irrelevant
}
echo Continuing
```

and

```
set -e
( [ -f "doesntExist" && { : ; } )
echo Continuing
```

is that in the former, your script sees an AND-list with a non-zero exit status, but in the latter it sees a subshell with a non-zero exit status.